# Is Windows really using the 3D Graphic Card?

Tags: windows, graphics-card, desktop, integrated-graphics

I'm wondering if Windows 7 or 8 (even dropped transparency!) is really using the power of a dedicated graphic card?

Is there any **remarkable** influence on the speed of **daily windows usage** (word processing, E-Mail, internet browsing etc.)?

*I do **not** speak of the performance within Games, Graphic Programs etc. For that I find enough benchmarks*

This would answer the question for many users that are looking for new computer with a integrated gaphics card or not.

Comment: Is it using it? Sure.  Will you notice a difference?  Almost certainly not.

Comment: Interesting. More relevant as larger monitors, and more of them are being used on a single system.  Especially important in realtime situations where CPU usage is critical like a Digital Audio Workstation.

Comment: So 90% of the users won't even notice a difference having a >300$ graphic card while using windows compared to a integrated graphics? Wow - don't tell ATI or nVidia!

Comment: @FiveO No, there won't be a noticeable difference anything with a video card > $50 installed for 90% of users.

Comment: @hydroparadise - I might expand on that even further and say that not only do most people not need a $300 graphics card for "word processing, E-Mail, internet browsing etc.", they could probably manage with a $300 *computer*.  (At that point you can start to tell a difference, maybe, but certainly nobody needs to spend four figures for clerical work.)

Comment: Of note, using Windows 7 or windows 8 without a graphics card which can provide 2d acceleration (or disabling acceleration) will be very noticeable. But as mentioned, the lowest-end graphics cards on the market these days can provide that. Both 7 and 8 try to offload desktop composting to the graphics card.

Comment: @FiveO I'm sure ATI and nVidia are aware of that. They're also aware that people who buy $300+ graphics cards usually buy them for gaming, running CAD software or similar workloads that stress the GPU. It doesn't matter that for regular desktop applications there's virtually no difference between those cards and integrated graphics from 4-5 years ago.

Comment: @Indrek - 2D benchmark numbers on cards from the big two have been stagnant for years, too.  They don't even *care* about it.  Matrox cards from 5 years ago have better 2D rendering speeds.

Comment: @Shinrai Well stated.  Nvidia used to sport their Quadro cards as 2D accellerators for CAD systems, but it's all 3D these days.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This depends a lot on your definitions:

Is Windows really using a *3D* card for daily stuff? No, not really.
Is Windows really using *hardware accelerated compositing* for daily stuff? Most definitely.

Do you need a $300 card for 2D acceleration & Aero? No. Pretty much any on-board graphics produced in the past few years will provide that these days, and I wouldn't factor it into any decisions about buying a new computer. It's not really a question of *how good* the 2D acceleration is, the card just needs to support it.

If you uninstall your drivers or disable hardware acceleration, you'll quickly notice the difference once you start dragging windows around on screen.

Comment: Yep, that pretty much says it all. I was just writing an answer, but Darth Android said it all.